# Updating a null cell - this stored procedure isn't working - why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

im doing a gym software. i have a signin signout system.when members sign in this data is put in a table leaving the signout colomn empty.then when member sign out the signout cell is updated.up to here is fine. but if the member signed in and out twice i dont want the sigout time of the first time to be changed.i want only the null cell to  be updated or where the signin time is max. i have the following stored procedure with no errors but when running nothin is happening to the signout cell!

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[updateSignOutMem]
@ID nvarchar(50), @signOut nvarchar(50),@date nvarchar(50)
as
update [DateTable]
set SignOut  = @signOut 

where ID = @ID AND [Date] = @date and SignOut = null ;
```

Answer (score 3):

**Solution**: Replace `SignOut = null` with `SignOut IS NULL`.

**Why**: Comparisons with NULL always return NULL, and a WHERE clause that evaluates to NULL is treated as FALSE. For example `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE NULL = NULL` will return zero records rather than the whole table.

**Explanation**: A `NULL` value is an "unknown" value, so the result of comparing two unknown values is also unknown. A description of this three-valued logic (true, false, unknown) can [be found on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29#Three-valued_logic_.283VL.29).

---

**PS**: SQL Server provides [much more data types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx) than just nvarchar(50). Use them! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try writing

```
SignOut IS null
```